# In html what's the purpose of using 'step' attribute in input tag?

Tags: html, xhtml

the purpose of using  step attribute in input tag in html?

```
    input type="number" name="points" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30"
```

From the above line minimum length is zero, maximum length is 100, default value is 30 but i can't understand what action doing when assign step="10"

Comment: When you change its value it will be done in `step` sizes. For example with `step="10"`, you can go from `value="30"` to either `20` or `40`, but not to for example `31` or `29`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step attribute specifies the legal number intervals for an  element. 
Example: in your case, step="10", legal numbers could be -10, 0, 10, 20, etc.
Still if you can't get it, you can go through this link.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_step

Answer (score 4):

You can think of `Step` as how many steps you have to move from the current value.

For example,

```
<input type="number" name="points" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30" />
```

Imagine yourself in a staircase. Here if you imagine `value` to be the stair number on which you are standing, `step` is the next `x` number of steps after which you can stop.

In your case you start with `value="30"`, means you are standing on stair number 30 and your `step="10"` means you can only stop at stair number `40`,`50`,`60` etc.

If your `value="31"` means you are standing on stair number 31 and your `step="10"` means you can only stop at stair number `41`,`51`,`61`, etc.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. `step` behaves as described only when `min` is not set. When `min="0"`, as in your code, `step` disallows any value that is not a multiple of `step`. So if you set `value="31"` in your example, the next allowed numbers are `40`, `50`, `60`, etc., not `41`, `51`, `61`, etc. See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The step attribute is used to state what steps between the min and max value are allowed. In this case the values 0, 10, 20, ..., 100 are allowed, not for example 12 or 57.

Do note that support for this in browsers is quite patchy at the moment, so you can't rely on the value sent to the server to actually be only one of the allowed ones.

And there is no length defined in that element. It is the minimum and maximum values that specified.

Answer (score 0):

`step` specifies the interval between a permitted value and the next. If users enter a value that is not permitted, the form does not submit. In the case of `input type="number"`, you can step through permitted values with the stepper on the right side of the input field.

**Example 1**: `<input type="number" step="10">`

Permitted values are ...-20, -10, 0, 10, 20...

**Example 2**: `<input type="number" step="10" value="5">`

In the absence of any `min` attribute, setting 5 as the default value makes it a permitted value. Hence, permitted numbers are ...-15, -5, 5, 15, 25...

**Example 3**: `<input type="number" step="10" value="5" min="0">`

Now that a `min` attribute is set, permitted values are positive multiples of `step`, offset by `min`. Hence, despite being the default value, *5 is not a permitted value in this example*. Permitted values are 0, 10, 20, 30, 40...

Consequently, in your example, permitted numbers are 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90.

Below is an implementation of all three examples so you can verify yourself.

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5em 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Implementation</th>
      <th scope="col">Permitted values</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><code>&lt;input type="number" step="10"&gt;</code></td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="number" step="10">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>...-20, -10, 0, 10, 20...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><code>&lt;input type="number" step="10" value="5"&gt;</code></td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="number" step="10" value="5">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>...-15, -5, 5, 15, 25...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><code>&lt;input type="number" step="10" value="5" min="0"&gt;</code></td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="number" step="10" value="5" min="0">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>0, 10, 20, 30, 40...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```